# How to create your own hash sha3 in django?

Tags: python, django

I can not add my hash(sha3_512) using hashlib in django.

My password is hashing 2 times:by me and by django automatically.

```
def hashing(password):
    password = hashlib.sha3_512(password.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    return password
```

I want to disable django hashing and use only my function.

Comment: Here you have documentation for your problem: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/passwords/#password-management-in-django

Comment: You can alter the `PASSWORD_HASHERS` setting: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#password-hashers

Comment: Think carefully about whether you want to write your own hasher like this - note that you are not salting the password like Django does, so it could be cracked more easily using rainbow tables.

Answer (score 0):

Django has probably the best documentation in the open-source world.

Here's the topic you're interested in: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/passwords/#writing-your-own-hasher

When you look at the [actual implementation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py), you may read the following:

> When creating your own hasher, you need to override algorithm, verify(), encode() and safe_summary().

So you must create your class, something like the following:

```
class SHA3PasswordHasher(BasePasswordHasher):
    algorithm = "sha3_512"

    def encode(self, password, salt):
        # implement here

    def verify(self, password, encoded):
        # implement here


    def safe_summary(self, encoded):
        # implement here

    def harden_runtime(self, password, encoded):
        pass
```

And then in `settings.py`:

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'mymodule.SHA3PasswordHasher',
]
```